# soap in PHP, can't make it work

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i am getting this error

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am tryingto learn how to use a soap service from php, ive done this with c# and just trying new things. but i get the above error and i dont know why, this is the call im trying to access "[call](https://onlineavl2api-mx.navmanwireless.com/onlineavl/api/V1.3/service.asmx?op=DoLogin)"

ill attach c# if it helps on something.

Thanks!

Code php

```
<?php
        try{
            $opts = array(
                'https'=>array(
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                    ));
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $userC = array("UserName"=>"pato.api",
                            "Password"=>"745477",
                            "ApplicationID"=>getGUID(),
                            "ClientID"=>getGUID());
            $Session = array("SessionId"=>getGUID());
            $soap_client = new SoapClient("https://onlineavl2api-mx.navmanwireless.com/onlineavl/api/V1.3/service.asmx?WSDL",array("stream_context" => $context,"cache_wsdl" => "WSDL_CACHE_NONE"));
            $request = array("UserCredentials"=>$userC,"Session"=>$Session,"IPAdress"=>"0.0.0.0","ClockVerificationUtc"=>date("Y-m-d") . 'T' . date("H:i:s"));
            $vec = array("request"=>$request);
            $quote = $soap_client->DoLogin($vec);
            echo $quote->DoLoginResponse;
        } catch (SoapFault $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }


        function getGUID(){
            if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
                return com_create_guid();
            }else{
                mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
                $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
                $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
                $uuid =substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
                    .substr($charid,20,12);
        return $uuid;
            }
        }

        ?>
```

Code C#

```
public DoLoginResponse Login()
        {
            var Client = new ServiceSoapClient();
            var request = new DoLoginRequest()
            {
                Session = new SessionInfo()
                {
                    SessionId = Guid.NewGuid()
                },
                UserCredential = new UserCredentialInfo()
                {
                    UserName = _User,
                    Password = _Password,
                    ApplicationID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ClientID = Guid.NewGuid()
                }
            };
            var response = new DoLoginResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check using the following update on your php script [uses **UserCredential**],

```
$request = array("UserCredential"=>$userC,"Session"=>$Session,"IPAdress"=>"127.0.0.0","ClockVerificationUtc"=>date("Y-m-d") . 'T' . date("H:i:s"));
```

And also you are missing "ClientVersion" parameter from this decleration,

```
    $userC = array("UserName"=>"pato.api",
                "Password"=>"745477",
                "ApplicationID"=>getGUID(),
                "ClientID"=>getGUID(),
                "ClientVersion"=>"your_client_version"
                );
```